# Need to perform two transformation for the same content in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two different transformation.After first transformation get over second need to be applied but not able to do.I have referred other stackoverflow post but its not working for me.

### Sample Input:

```
<Para>1<AAA>2<BBB>3</BBB>4</AAA>5</Para>
```

Requirement is like BBB may available outside of AAA as well.We need to remove all AAA and put the value in comma separated format.

### Expected output after First:

```
 <Para>12<BBB>3</BBB>45</Para>
```

### Expected output on the Second:

```
<Para>12,3,45</Para>
```

### First:

Here i am just removing tag AAA from the content.And retriving its content and child.

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match ="*/AAA">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
```

### Second:

Here I am just appending comma between the node element by removing all the tags inside para and retrieving its content.

```
<xsl:param name="Para"></xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="Para">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:variable name="BBB-element-exists">
            <xsl:for-each select="node()[self::BBB ][normalize-space(.)!='']">
            <xsl:if test="(self::Change and (child::BBB)) or (self::BBB)">
            <xsl:value-of select="'BBBexists'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$BBB-element-exists = 'BBBexists'">
                <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
                <xsl:if test="position() >1 and not(parent::Change) ">
                <xsl:value-of select="','" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$BBB-element-exists != 'BBBexists'">
             <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, output you want and output you get to allow us to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your response. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use at least one mode to separate processing of the second step from the first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*/AAA">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/node()" mode="step2"/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para" mode="step2">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:variable name="BBB-element-exists">
            <xsl:for-each select="node()[self::BBB ][normalize-space(.)!='']">
            <xsl:if test="(self::Change and (child::BBB)) or (self::BBB)">
            <xsl:value-of select="'BBBexists'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$BBB-element-exists = 'BBBexists'">
                <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
                <xsl:if test="position() >1 and not(parent::Change) ">
                <xsl:value-of select="','" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$BBB-element-exists != 'BBBexists'">
             <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```